# Parsing XML into a HTML list

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, xslt

I' ve got a XML, which I parsed into a PHP array. It looks like this:

```
Array
(
  [Album] => Array
  (
    [id] => 12
    [name] => My album
    [id_parent] => 0
    [row] => Array
    (
      [Album] => Array
      (
        [row] => Array
        (
          [id] => 14
          [name] => Another album
          [id_parent] => 12
          [Photos] => Array
          (
            [row] => Array
            (
              [0] => Array
              (
                [id] => 1078
                [name] => My first photo
                [Album] => Array
                (
                  [row] => Array
                  (
                    [name] =>Another album
                    [id] => 15
                    [Photos] => Array
                    (
                      [row] => Array
                      (
                        [0] => Array
                        (
                          [id] => 1069
                          [name] => Summer photo
                          [checked] => [checked]                                                                                                        
                        )
```

and so on.
How can I parse it into a HTML list (in nested ul's), to get something like

```
My album
-Another album
--My first photo
---Another album
----Summer photo
---[end Another album]
--[end My first photo]
-[end Another album]
[end My album]
```

Albums and photos are just samples. i need to find a way how to parse it to HTML.

EDIT:
Okay, I add something what I really meant - "checked" node. I simply need to put the parent node into  tags.

Comment: What is the problem exaclty? Can't you just loop through your data and output some HTML data?

Comment: I've just eddited an array. Could someone look at this and help somehow?

Comment: I can't really understand your question: you want to go from HTML to XML, but the sample you've posted is neither. Could you post your desired input and output?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a quick XSLT transform to do it.
If you post a sample of the base XML I can point you in the right direction, but otherwise, check out the examples at these two links. With a little modification they can do what you want.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog